# Select button in Full Calendar [React]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar

I need to add a select button to the toolbar of full calendar, how ever i don't think i can to this with full calendar, because i can just use basic buttons there. Is there a way to add a select button to full calendar toolbar ? [this select button must be in the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbKg3.png)

Comment: Add some of your relevant code to the question

Comment: When you say a "select button", do you mean a button, or a HTML `<select>` - i.e. a dropdown list? `<select>` is technically not a button. With fullCalendar, you can add buttons to the toolbar using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons but it's not easy to add other types of content.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you just have to add headerToolbar property in your Fullcalendar component

```
headerToolbar={{
        start: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
        center: 'prev title next',
        end: 'today ',
      }}
```

Like this:

```
<FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionGridPlugin]}
          initialView={'dayGridMonth'}
          headerToolbar={{
            start: 'title',
            center: '',
            end: 'today prev,next',
          }}
        />
```

Now adjust comma or spacing according to your desired format.